# How do I group my child nodes to it's corresponding parent node?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am new to C#/ASP.Net. and I have a project now that involves binding a tree from two SQL Table. I've done some home work.. and I was able to bind my tree. first here are my tables. My goal is to group my child to it's corresponding parent. but what happens is it the child goes into all the parents. I know i am almost there but i got stuck. :(

```
tblCategory(parentnodes)
categoryID(varchar(20))
Category(varchar(50))
active(char(1))

tblDocuments(childnodes)
id(int)
description(varchar(100))
title(varchar(20))
categoryid(varchar(20))

tblcategory.categoryid = tbldocuments.categoryid
```

here are my codes.

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //bindtree
            DataTable dtCategoryNodes = new DataTable();
            dtCategoryNodes = content.dtCategoryNodes();
            dtCategoryNodes.AcceptChanges();

            DataTable dtNodes = new DataTable();
            dtNodes = content.GetNodes();
            dtNodes.AcceptChanges();

            TreeNode CategoryNode = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < dtCategoryNodes.Rows.Count; i++)

            {
                string categoryid = dtCategoryNodes.Rows[i]["CategoryID"].ToString();

                CategoryNode = new TreeNode(dtCategoryNodes.Rows[i]
                "CATEGORY"].ToString());

                CategoryNode.Collapse();
                for (int j = 0; j < dtNodes.Rows.Count; j++)
                {   string parentid = dtNodes.Rows[j]["parentid"].ToString();

                    TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode(dtNodes.Rows[j]["TITLE"].ToString());
                    CategoryNode.ChildNodes.Add(childNode);


                }        

                tvContents.Nodes.Add(CategoryNode);
                tvContents.DataBind();
              }
            }
          }
```

but i had a problem here. here is what happened to my tree.

```
a. Crift Items 
 a.1Configuring DCOM 

b.Internal Refresher Trainings 
 b.1Configuring DCOM 

c. Product/Process Update 
 c.1 Configuring DCOM 

d.Promotions/Discounts 
 d.1 Configuring DCOM 

e.QA Update 
 e.1 Configuring DCOM
```

below is my data
    tbldocument
    id   Title             File     CategoryID
    1    Configuring DCOM  DCOM.doc PRODUPDT

```
tblCategory
CategoryID  Category                    active
CRIFT   Crift Items                 Y
IRTRAIN Internal Refresher Trainings    Y
PRODUPDT    Product/Process Update          Y
PROMODISCS  Promotions/Discounts            Y
QAUPDT  QA Update                   Y
```

Appreciate all comments and suggestions! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
for (int j = 0; j < dtNodes.Rows.Count; j++)
{   string parentid = dtNodes.Rows[j]["parentid"].ToString();
    TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode(dtNodes.Rows[j]["TITLE"].ToString());
    CategoryNode.ChildNodes.Add(childNode);
}
```

With

```
foreach(DataRow drChild in dtNodes.Select("CategoryID=" + categoryid))
{   
    TreeNode childNode = new TreeNode(drChild["TITLE"].ToString());
    CategoryNode.ChildNodes.Add(childNode);
}
```

Comment: hi Arun! sorry for the late reply... thanks for your advice. I've tried it but I think I missed some points on my code. here is what i did.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < dtCategoryNodes.Rows.Count; i++)
 {
 CategoryID = dtCategoryNodes.Rows[i]["CategoryID"].ToString();
 CategoryNode = new TreeNode(dtCategoryNodes.Rows[i] ["CATEGORY"].ToString());
 CategoryNode.Collapse();
 dtChildNodes = content.GetChildNodes(CategoryID);
 
for (int j = 0; j < dtChildNodes.Rows.Count; j++)
  {
string parentid = dtChildNodes.Rows[j]["parentid"].ToString();
string url = dtChildNodes.Rows[j]["url"].ToString();
ChildNode = new TreeNode(dtChildNodes.Rows[j]["TITLE"].ToString());
CategoryNode.ChildNodes.Add(ChildNode);
}
 tvContents.Nodes.Add(CategoryNode);
}

Comment: Are you getting an error or incorrect behaviour ? Your code seems to be ok assuming everything does what it's supposed to and you have your variables declared.